# Usage of "wouldn't work" vs "didn't work" when talking about past experience / observation

Tags: meaning-in-context, single-word-requests

Today at the airport someone said, "You can do that by pressing this button". The other person replied, "I tried that, but it **wouldn't** work".

It seems that they meant "it **didn't** work". 
Is "it **wouldn't** work" correct in this context (and why?),
and how does it differ from "it **didn't** work" (if at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "did not" is just a simple description of what happened, "would not" implies a **decision**: the use of "wouldn't" here gives the button a "personality" - it implies that the button refused to work, like a small child refusing to put her coat on.  It also implies that pressing the button **should** have had the desired result (which might not actually be the case).

Obviously this is not strictly correct, since a button cannot make a choice about anything - it's just a component in a machine.  But, this choice of words lends a bit of humour to the situation - One could picture the speaker pressing the button, and the button saying "No!" in a petulant voice.  So, it might have been used deliberately, to add a bit of humour.

Or, it may simply have been a mistake.

Comment: thanks, so if we model a situation with a child and I say "I asked him to clean the room, and he wouldn't do it", does it mean that he refused to clean it? whereas if I said "he didn't clean it" it might be that he simply forgot?

Comment: @MaxWizardK yes, exactly.